# NHibernate not updating parent object's table when using event listeners

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to add audit fields to my domain objects before they are inserted or updated by utilizing NHibernate event listeners. Utilizing the `IPreInsert` and `IPreUpdate` event listener interfaces, I am able to set the auditing fields on all the domain objects except for those that have the auditing fields stored in a parent object's table. For example, here are my entity classes:

```
public class Person : Entity
{
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class Entity : PersistentEntity
{
   public int EntityTypeId {get; set;}
}

public abstract class PersistentEntity
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set;}
   public virtual Guid UpdateUser {get; set;}
   public virtual DateTime UpdateDate {get; set;}
}
```

Here are my mappings:

```
public class PersonMap : SubclassMap<Person>
{
   Map(x => x.Name);
}

public class EntityMap : PersistentEntityMap<Entity>
{
   Map(x => x.EntityTypeId);
}

public abstract class PersistentEntityMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : PersistentEntityMap
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    Map(x => x.UpdateUser);
    Map(x => x.UpdateDate);
}
```

And here is how the tables are defined:

Person Table:

- Id
- Name

Entity Table:

- Id
- EntityTypeId
- UpdateUser
- UpdateDate

So given this setup, the `IPreInsert` event listener works perfectly, inserting a new person into the person table and inserting a new `Entity` into the `Entity` table with `UpdateUser` and `UpdateDate` correctly populated. However, if I where to update the person's name, the `IPreUpdate` event listener fires and does change the `UpdateDate` field on the object, but an update on the entity table is never performed. Taking advise from this page,

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/changing-values-in-nhibernate-events.aspx

I tried using both `IFlushEntity` and `ISaveOrUpdate` event listeners to no effect.